# Is $\varphi(0)^2$ a distribution_

Tags: distribution-theory

For $F:D(R)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ define $F(\varphi)=\varphi(0)^2$. Now is the given function a distribution?

Comment: Have you checked the definition of "distribution"?

Answer (score 1):

A distribution has to be a linear map, could you conclude about that one ?